# OrderBy in Calculated Columns in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Database Table for a discussion forum as follows.  ParentID tracks the parent topic if the row represents as reply.

```
ID  Subject   Body   ParentID
```

In generating a list of topics, I would like to order topics by the number of replies for each topic. Is there a way to dynamically add a calculated column and query the same table for each topic?

```
List<Topic> topics = (from element in Posts where ParentID is null).OrderBy(m => m.Replies).ToList();
```

The problem is I don't have a Replies column persisted in the database and want to calculate it at runtime.  Can I use a let keyword or similar?

Comment: the classes are partial so you can use this concept. Just add you calculated field there. but be carefull with filtering on the calculated field.

Comment: Can a reply itself have replies or will the `ParentID` only ever refer to a record that doesn't itself have a `ParentID` value?

Comment: LINQ what?  Just LINQ is not a data access technology.  LINQ to SQL?  LINQ to Entities, i.e. the LINQ provider for Entity Framework?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

*This code is, however, untested. It will only count its direct descendants.*

```
List<Topic> topics = Posts.Where(x => x.ParentID == null)
                          .GroupJoin(Posts.Where(x => x.ParentID != null),
                                   parent => parent.ID,
                                   reply => reply.ParentID,
                                   (parent, reply) => new { Posts = parent, Reply = reply.Count() })
                          .OrderBy (x => x.Reply)
                          .Select(x => x.Posts)
                          .ToList<Topic>();
```